# Give IIS 6.0 permission to modify app.config files

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, permissions

to install a web application I need to give write permission for IIS 6.0 application to modify the App.config file.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the `NETWORK SERVICE` (or whatever system account IIS is using) account write permissions to the config file?

To do this, navigate to the config file in windows explorer, right-click and select properties. Under the security tab add the `NETWORK SERVICE` account with write permissions.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to do that? thanks. (I'm not experienced in this)

Comment: I tried this. and still getting the "No Write Access to App Settings". do you think the IIS uses another account? Thanks